# VoidCallback x Function qual a diferença?

Tags: flutter, dart

Na documentação informa que

```
part of dart.ui;
/// Signature of callbacks that have no arguments and return no data.
typedef VoidCallback = void Function();
```

Pelo que entendi `VoidCallback` é um 'apelido' para `void Function()` e utilizado apenas onde se utiliza a parte gráfica (UI) do flutter, é isso mesmo ou tem mais alguma diferença?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Pelo que entendi VoidCallback é um 'apelido' para void Function()

Correto. Por ser open-source, você mesmo conferiu que é o mesmo que uma função que não tem retorno, e não recebe parâmetros. Isso também pode ser conferido na [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html).

> 2) utilizado apenas onde se utiliza a parte gráfica (UI) do flutter

Imagino que você tenha deduzido isso por conta da linha 
`part of dart.ui`. Segundo a [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/dart-ui-library.html) desse import:

> > Built-in types and core primitives for a Flutter application.
>
> Tipos embutidos e primitivas principais para uma aplicação Flutter.
>
> > [...] such as classes for driving the input, graphics text, layout, and rendering subsystems.
>
> [...] tais quais classes para dirigir a entrada da dados, gráficos, layout e renderizar sub-sistemas
>
> (Do link acima, tradução livre)

Portanto, podemos perceber que este import não trata apenas da parte **gráfica**, mas de qualquer outro exemplo dentre os citados.

É importante notar que não é porque esse `typedef` foi definido nesse import que ele precisa ser utilizado única e exclusivamente com os mesmos objetivos. Ele nada mais é do que um `apelido`, uma comodidade para evidenciar qual tipo de função espera-se. Quando alguém lê `VoidCallback`  é imediato do que se trata.

> 3) é isso mesmo ou tem mais alguma diferença?

É só isso mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Não existe diferença, é só uma forma simples de usar o tipo, é a biblioteca usando um recurso da linguagem para facilitar o uso, o `typedef` não adiciona funcionalidade, ele apenas gera o apelido mesmo. Provavelmente faz isso porque usa muito.