# Erro na função que eu criei

Tags: flutter

Estou estudando e praticando *Flutter*. Porém o curso que acompanho não está com a versão mais recente do Flutter, o que fez eu me deparar com os seguintes erros:

> The parameter 'onPress' can't have a value of 'null' because of its
> type, but the implicit default value is 'null'. Try adding either an
> explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

e

> The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'.

Pesquisei, mas não consegui resolver. Segue o código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MeuApp());

// ignore: use_key_in_widget_constructors
class MeuApp extends StatelessWidget {
  btnAction() {
    print("Clicou no botão");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Meu primeiro App")),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Exemplo(
                  title: ('Texto 01'),
                  onPress: () {
                    print('Clicou no Item 01');
                  }),
              Exemplo(
                  title: ('Texto 02'),
                  onPress: () {
                    print('Clicou no Item 02');
                  }),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}

class Exemplo extends StatelessWidget {
  Exemplo({
    this.title,
    this.onPress,
  });

  var title;
  Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (title == null) {
      title = 'Titulo Reserva';
    }

    return Container(
        width: 200,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        color: Colors.cyan,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text('Texto de Exemplo'),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(title),
              onPressed: onPress,
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você cria um construtor utilizando a notação das chaves (`{}`), esses parâmetros são nomeados e *opcionais*.

Como eles são opcionais, caso alguém chame esse construtor sem passar esses parâmetros, o compilador aceita. Nesse caso é o mesmo que passar um valor nulo:

```
// No caso do seu exemplo, isso
Exemplo()
// É igual a:
Exemplo(title: null, onPressed: null);
```

Quando você declarou suas variáveis, você definiu elas sem o sinal de interrogação (`?`). Isto é, elas não podem receber valores nulos. Seguindo seu exemplo:

```
String title; // Não pode ser nulo
String? title; // Pode receber valores nulos
```

Para ser possível utilizar parâmetros nomeados, e ao mesmo tempo, ter esses parâmetros como não nulos, você deve usar a notação `required`:

```
Exemplo({
    required this.title,
    required this.onPress,
  });
```

E isso deve ser suficiente pra resolver o primeiro erro.

Para saber mais, leia o tour da linguagem, [aqui](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters) (em inglês). Já coloquei o link pra parte da página referente a esse assunto.

Sobre o segundo erro, você não deu detalhes sobre qual linha exatamente ocorre, mas imagino que você precise explicitar que sua função é do tipo certo para um botão (uma função que não tem retorno, e não recebe parâmetros). Experimente definir como tal:

```
final VoidCallback? onPress;
```

[VoidCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html) é um atalho (ou apelido) que o próprio Dart já tem. Ela é o mesmo tipo que você precisa, isto é: `void Function();`

Se tiver curiosidade sobre esse *typedef* (atalho/apelido para tipos), existe essa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/432243/152025) no próprio site.

Comment: O Erro acontece quando tento chamar a função no botão
 children: [
            Text('Texto de Exemplo'),
            TextButton(
              child: Text(title),
              onPressed: onPress,
            )
          ],